# Using tensors are dictionary keys in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

i have seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879126/how-are-tensors-immutable-in-tensorflow). It is not what i am looking for.

I am running this on tensorflow2.0

I read the following sentence in the TensorFlow documentation:

> With the exception of tf.Variable, the value of a tensor is immutable,
>   which means that in the context of a single execution tensors only
>   have a single value. However, evaluating the same tensor twice can
>   return different values; for example that tensor can be the result of
>   reading data from disk, or generating a random number.

I tried using tensors as a dictionary key and i get the following error:

```
Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key
```

1. What does this error mean?
2. Are tf.Variables hashable as well? They also define a computation rather than being the computation, so why the distinction 'With the exception of tf.Variable, the value of a tensor is immutable' is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this error mean?

I guess you could find answers for the first question in the source code.

Looking at [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b72c1af2d4a28564c4820395604ebef94d4e2160/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L373) and the comment above, you have to explicitly enable hashing for tensors as follows.

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_tensor_equality()

x = tf.ones(shape=[10,2], dtype=np.float32)
dct = {x: 1} # Works fine
```

What happens is that now [`__hash__`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b72c1af2d4a28564c4820395604ebef94d4e2160/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L709) returns a proper ID instead of raising an error. Which allows you to use this as a key in a dictionary.

The downside to disabling this is that you can no longer perform element-wise comparisons with the tensor. For example,

```
x = tf.ones(shape=[10,2], dtype=np.float32)
print((x==1.0))
```

### With Equality enabled returns,

```
>>> tf.Tensor(
[[ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 ...
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]], shape=(10, 2), dtype=bool)
```

### With Equality disabled returns,

```
>>> False
```

> Are tf.Variables hashable as well? They also define a computation rather than being the computation, so why the distinction 'With the exception of tf.Variable, the value of a tensor is immutable' is there

Yes they are. If you look at `__hash__` function, it returns `id(self)` which will be unique for that object during that object's lifetime (source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753364/why-is-the-id-of-a-python-class-not-unique-when-called-quickly)). I don't know much about how hash ids are generated using `id`. But as long as it's unique shouldn't be a problem. And in fact you can change the variable value after it becomes a key in a dictionary too.